# Prove that for each $n \in Z$ the $3n^2-1$ is not the square of an integer

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

We assume that $3n^2-1 = p^2$ where $p \in Z$. I followed two approaches but I can not solve the problem.

First Approach:

$3n^2-1 = p^2 \rightarrow 3n^2 = p^2 + 1 \rightarrow 3n^2 = p*p + 1$

So,

$3n^2 \equiv 1 (mod p) $

Second Approach:

$3n^2-1= p^2 \rightarrow  3n^2 - p^2 = 1 \rightarrow (n*\sqrt{3} + p)(n*\sqrt{3} - p) = 1$

Can you give me a hint about how can I solve it ?

Comment: Show that $3m-1$ is not the square of an integer for any $m$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $3$ never divides $p^2+1$ for every positive integer $p$.

To prove this, you can consider the cases $p=3k, 3k+1, 3k+2$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, I have to prove that 3 can not divide the $p^2 +1$. Ok!!! Hint about this ? :)  Actually, my first thought was to prove what you say (it is the most straightforward), but  I miss something from the theory.

Comment: Just do a case distinction ($p=0,1 or 2\mod 3$) You will see that $p^2$ is never $2\mod 3$.

Comment: Try as @Quentin suggested. Namely, you can try $p = 3k,\ 3k+1,\ 3k+2$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Why do we want to prove that $p^2$ is never $2 mod 3$ ?

Comment: I think I got it !!! Thank you, please revise your answer based on the comments you write here. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The $n^2$ in the question would appear to be a red herring as it's quite simple to prove the stronger statement "For each $n \in \mathbb{N}, \;3n-1\;$ is not the square of an integer.

To see this, simply take any integer $k$, and consider the possible residues (mod 3); in each case it should be easy to show that $k^2 \not \equiv -1 \pmod 3$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** Use modular arithmetic to show that $$3n^2 \equiv 0 \mod3$$ and similarly $$3n^2 -1 \equiv 2 \mod3.$$

Can you show that no square is $\equiv 2\mod3 ?$

Answer (score 0):

A result similar to that obtained with reference to $\bmod 3$ in the previous answers can also be obtained by analysis $\bmod 4$.

The square of any odd number $\equiv 1 \bmod 4$

The square of any even number $\equiv 0 \bmod 4$

Substituting, $3n^2-1\equiv (2\ \text{or}\ -1) \bmod 4$, and no square $\equiv (2\ \text{or}\ -1) \bmod 4$ (see previous two statements).

Hence $3n^2-1$ cannot be a square.